# Line counting in C but exclude empty lines

Tags: c

I've got the following program, but there is a problem. First the program part that does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    char ch;
    char fnamer[100];
    char fnamer2[100];  //Storing File Path/Name of Image to Display
    printf("\n\nPlease Enter the Full Path of the Image file you want to view: \n");
    scanf("%s",&fnamer);
    fp=fopen(fnamer,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n\nPlease Enter the Full Path of the Image file you want to write to: \n");
    scanf("%s",&fnamer2);
    fp2=fopen(fnamer2,"w");
    if(fp2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        // printf("test\n");
    }



    int line_number = 0;
    int charsOnLine = 0;

    fprintf(fp2, "%d: ", ++line_number);  /* put line number in output file */
    printf("%d: ", line_number);


    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        //printf("test2");
        fputc(ch,fp2);
        printf("%c", ch);
        if ( ch != '\n' && charsOnLine ==0 )
        {
            fprintf(fp2, "%d:", ++line_number );  /* put line number in output file */
            printf("%d: ", line_number);
        }
        //        if (ch != '\n' && charsOnLine 0 ){
        //          fprintf(fp2, "%c", ch);
        //        printf("%d", ch);
        //  }
    }

    fclose;
    fclose(fp);
    // fclose(fp2);
    // getch();
}
```

The program needs to count the lines, give them a number but skip the blank lines. But here is the problem: when I run this code it gives all the chars a number.

Comment: To begin with, note that [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an `int`. This is actually important when you want to compare the returned character with `EOF`. As for your problem, try stepping through the code in a debugger. That should make the problem with your conditions pretty obvious.

Comment: It seems that you never change `charsOnLine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag to remember when you have just started a new line. The first time you see a char not equal to `'\n'`, you print the line number and clear the flag.

Something like:

```
int line_number = 0;
int newLine = 1;

while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
{
    if (ch == '\n')
    {
        newLine = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (newLine)
        {
            fprintf(fp2, "%d:", ++line_number );
            printf("%d: ", line_number);
            newLine = 0;
        }
    }
    fputc(ch,fp2);
    printf("%c", ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the program needs to count the lines and append their content.
Then I would search for `'\n'` char, rather than skipping it with `if (ch != '\n')`

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    char ch;
    char fnamer[100];
    char fnamer2[100];  //Storing File Path/Name of Image to Display
    printf("\n\nPlease Enter the Full Path of the Image file you want to view: \n");
    scanf("%s",&fnamer);
    fp=fopen(fnamer,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n\nPlease Enter the Full Path of the Image file you want to write to: \n");
    scanf("%s",&fnamer2);
    fp2=fopen(fnamer2,"w");
    if(fp2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }


    int line_number = 0;
    fprintf(fp2, "%d: ", ++line_number );

    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        if ( ch == '\n' )
        {
            fprintf(fp2, "%d: ", ++line_number );  /* put line number in output file */
        }
        else {
            fputc(ch,fp2); /* put the char in the corresponding line */
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```